# How do I query elements containing attributeNameA with namespaceB with "css"?

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, css-selectors, nokogiri

My problem is different than "[How can I get the values of attributes with namespace, using Nokogiri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535509/how-can-i-get-the-values-of-attributes-with-namespace-using-nokogiri)".

my XML contains attributes with namespaces. How do I query elements containing attributeNameA with namespaceB (`namespaceB:attributeNameA="attributeAValue"`) using Nokogiri's `css` method?

This is my code:

```
xmlContent = %Q|
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns1:el1 xmlns:ns1="blabla" >
    <ns1:el2 ns1:att="123">with namespace</ns1:el2 >
    <ns1:el2 att="noNameSpace">no namespace</ns1:el2 >
</ns1:el1>|
xml_doc  = Nokogiri::XML(xmlContent)

#no namespace
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2[att]')
result.each {|i| puts i}

#with namespace
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2[ns1|att]') #error unexpexted '|'
result.each {|i| puts i}
```

Edited jan 6 2011:
From this link:
https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/257#issuecomment-3365636 Nokogiri does not support querying xml elements with namespaced attribute directly.

The real use case is modifying SSIS package (*.dtsx); I cannot query all elements with attribute DTS:Name containing "projectVar_".

I will have to inform nokogiri team for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

When you parse your document, Nokogiri is trying to make sense of it and failing to understand the namespace declaration:

```
puts xml_doc.errors
```

returns:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document>]
```

This is because of the XML DECL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Removing that clears up that problem.

The way you are accessing the attributes of the nodes isn't right either:

```
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2[att]')
result.each {|i| puts i}
```

should be:

```
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2')
result.each { |i| puts i['att'] }
```

The attempt to access a namespaced node's attribute with a namespace on it is odd. I don't remember ever seeing a namespaced attribute. Nokogiri doesn't seem to like it either:

If I run this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xmlContent = %Q|
<ns1:el1 xmlns:ns1="blabla">
  <ns1:el2 ns1:att="123">with namespace</ns1:el2 >
  <ns1:el2 att="noNameSpace">no namespace</ns1:el2 >
</ns1:el1>|

xml_doc = Nokogiri::XML(xmlContent)
puts xml_doc.errors 

puts "Searching for: 'att' attribute"
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2')
result.each { |i| puts i['att'] }

puts "Searching for: 'ns1|att' attribute"
result = xml_doc.css('ns1|el2')
result.each { |i| puts i['ns1|att'] }
```

I get this:

```
Searching for: 'att' attribute
123
noNameSpace
Searching for: 'ns1|att' attribute
```

---

```
result.first # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8051e19c name="el2" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x8051f344 prefix="ns1" href="blabla"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x8051e084 name="att" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x8051f344 prefix="ns1" href="blabla"> value="123">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x80519e30 "with namespace">]>
result.first.keys # => ["att"]
result.first.values # => ["123"]
result.first['att'] # => "123"
result.first['ns1|att'] # => nil
result.first['ns1:att'] # => nil

result.last # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x8051356c name="el2" namespace=#<Nokogiri::XML::Namespace:0x8051f344 prefix="ns1" href="blabla"> attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x805133a0 name="att" value="noNameSpace">] children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x805122d4 "no namespace">]>
result.last.keys # => ["att"]
result.last.values # => ["noNameSpace"]
result.last['att'] # => "noNameSpace"
result.last['ns1|att'] # => nil
result.last['ns1:att'] # => nil
```

Comment: There's nothing special about namespaced attributes. The selector syntax that the OP is using seems fine, but I can't say much else since I've never used Nokogiri (and I'm not a Ruby programmer).

Comment: The OP should probably take that to the Nokogiri development team. They're very responsive.

Comment: Thanks Tin Man, I was trying to edit SSIS package directly with nokogiri, and dtsx files contains namespaced attributes. since nokogiri does not support this feature, I have to use regular string gsub instead.

Comment: @kite, I added a bit more code to make it more visible what was going on. Ask your question on the Nokogiri-Talk mail list. You can find info on the "[Getting Help](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/getting_help.html)" page.